# MongoDB: Query a array of json object using operation like gte and lte

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of Promo codes like this:-

```
{
   'promoCode': 'XMAS22',
   'country': 'USA',
   'isExpirable': true,
   'availability'  : [
       {
            'startTimestamp' :  startTimeVal1,
            'endTimestamp':  endTimeVal1,
            'timezone': 'America/New_York'
       },
       {
            'startTimestamp' :  startTimeVal2,
            'endTimestamp':  endTimeVal2',
            'timezone': 'America/Chicago'
       },
       {
            'startTimestamp' :  startTimeVal3,
            'endTimestamp':  endTimeVal3,
            'timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
       },
    ]
},
{
   'promoCode': 'HAPPYDAY',
   'country': 'USA',
   'isExpirable': false,
   'availability'  : null
}
```

1. Promo Code `XMAS22` is expirable in nature. So it has `isExpirable` status as `true` and has anvailability array, containing availability based on three timezones.
2. Promo code `HAPPYDAY` has `isExpirable` status `false`, so availability is null.

A user sends a timestamp value and a timezone. Something like `1628290101` and `'America/New_York'`. The query should retrieve:-

```
{
   'promoCode': 'XMAS22',
   'country': 'USA'
},
{
   'promoCode': 'HAPPYDAY',
   'country': 'USA'
}
```

Promo code XMAS22 should be retrieved if:-

1. isExpirable = true and,
2. timezone value is gte startTimestamp and lte endTimestamp and,
3. timezone = America/New_York

Promo code HAPPYDAY should be retrieved because:-

1. isExpirable = false

How can I build up the query?

Comment: Did you try https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/ ? as a side note 1628290101 looks like a unix timestamp. Unix epoch started abstract time which doesn't have concept of timezones. It depends only on Cs133 transition frequency and is agnostic to human's cultural/political borders, geographies, or even planets for that matter.

Comment: @AlexBlex Unix timestamps are actually a UTC time converted to timestamp. Say, 25-12-2022 22:10:00 New_York time would be converted into UTC time and then converted into timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- here we assume the user endered `timestamp=5` and `timezone="America/New_York"`
- its the conditions you said, to pass if `isExpirable=false` or same timezone and timestamp between the start and end time.
- finally project to keep only those 2 fields you want, you can remove the `_id : 0`  also if you want

*this is the find way with only query operators to use the index if you have one on `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp`, we could do the same with aggregation in more programatic way with `$filter` but index wouldn't be used even if you had it.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=638cc9b3424f6130d7f12171)

```js
find({"$or": 
 [{"isExpirable": {"$eq": false}},
   {"$and": 
     [{"availability": 
         {"$elemMatch": 
           {"$and": 
             [{"startTimestamp": {"$lte": 5}}, {"endTimestamp": {"$gte": 5}},
               {"timezone": {"$eq": "America/New_York"}}]}}}]}]},
     {"projection": {"promoCode": 1, "country": 1}})
```